# How to fetch correct tokenID/accessToken with google sign in with a web app created with create-react-app and using firebase

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-signin

I am learning to react and implementing Google sign-in authentication. I am using google firebase as the backend. I want to do a set of operation precisely to say "Create an order" only when the user is authenticated. I am using `signInWithPopup` method and with `.then` I get a `result` object from which I extract `.credential.accessToken` and set it in a state. Then when I create the order I use that token to be passed with
`/orders.json?auth=<accessToken>`. But I get `401-unauthorized access` in return.
The Google user is created fine in firebase and it also updates its last signed in datestamp correctly in firebase.

Order Submit Code snippet :

```
axios
      .post("/orders.json?auth=" + accessToken, orders)
      .then(Response => {
        dispatch(submitOrderStart(Response.data.name, orders));
        alert("Order has been added..!!");
      })
```

Sign-in method code snippet:

```
firebaseApp
      .auth()
      .signInWithPopup(provider)
      .then(result => {
        console.log(result);
        this.props.onGoogleSignedIn(result);
      });
```

Rules defined in Firebase:

```
{

      "rules": {
            "ingredients" : {
                ".read": "true",
                ".write": "true"
            },
          "orders" : {
            ".read" : "auth != null",
            ".write" : "auth != null",
            ".indexOn" : ["userId"]
          }
      }
    }
```

Please let me know if more details are required. Thanks.

Comment: Are you passing the Google accessToken to your server? or to a google API?

Comment: I am passing it to my firebase backend. I don't have a dedicated server written for this and using firebase Realtime database. So I have this link /orders.json where I have all my orders saved and I access it using auth=<accessToken>.

Comment: Are you passing the Google access token or Firebase ID token to it? I assume you just need to pass the firebase ID token to verify on your backend and then process the order based on that.

Comment: Okay. Can you please suggest me from where I can fetch the same?